# Show percentage after prediction in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I've trained model with Keras which predicts tags according to post. After training it loops over 10 test posts and predicts tag. I also need to show accuracy of prediction for every post but I don't know what to do...
This is sample of the code.I would appreciate your help.

```
for i in range(10):
prediction = loaded_model.predict(np.array([x_test[i]]))
predicted_label = text_labels[np.argmax(prediction)]
print(test_posts.iloc[i][:50], "...")
print('Actual label:' + test_tags.iloc[i])
print("Predicted label: " + predicted_label + "\n")
```

Comment: If I understood properly, you need to print the corresponding prediction percent to the predicted label?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done a little test with some categories, [0, 1, ..., 9].
The function `predict` returns an array for the probability of each class.
So that, you could just print `max(prediction)` as long as it's category and whatever you need.